# Calling dll and c++ header file in a java program

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I know many people have asked similar question but i want to specifically ask how do we call both a .dll and a header file in one java program. In this program i must use the dll file and include the header file  if written in c++. But i am  not so good in using c++, i want to use java, so how to i achieve this? I know about jna which is good when calling dll files in java and jni, used when calling c/c++ files in java. But in this case, i need to use the dll file in a java program and the c++ header file must be included in order for the program to perform very well.

Comment: Hi Green, why must the C++ header file be included? The header file usually does not include any executable code, just a set of declarations, so it should not affect the performance of the program.

Comment: @urish According to the vendor of the library, you need to include  the header file into your program. Then you can call the functions provided by the library in your own program. When your program runs, it will dynamically link to the library.

Comment: This sounds like how most of the libraries work. I think the JNA will be your best call - in my opinion, much easier to set up and use in comparison with JNI, and you don't have to write any C/C++ code yourself or compile things for multiple platforms

Comment: @urish, i agree with you on jna, but jna works for dll files, then how do i implement the header file? Remember that the header file must be included in the program am going to write in order dynamically access the library.

Comment: Unless the header file includes some logic (like inline functions, etc.) you don't really need to include it. JNA takes care of dynamically access the library. You will have to declare the functions that are listed in the header file inside a Java class, using the JNA conventions, and this is all it takes for JNA to dynamically access the library.

Comment: @urish I guess you are right  about changing the header file to java, but i think i would have some challenges like changing pointer variables, struct identifiers, enum identifiers and the header file starts with 

#ifndef and ends with #endif 

and some variables have logic values

Comment: Yes, you will definitely have some challenges. But hey, that's why creating software is interesting :-) Good luck with this!